# Angular 1.6 + Components: passing constants between modules

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

How do I pass the value of a constant from one module to another? Thank you in advance. Here's the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hhojtzaTJvrReEBfvhfc?p=preview) demo. The constant "config" is defined in app.module.js, and I want to be able to pass it to the child.module.js for defining constant "childConfig". Right now the console is saying "config is not defined".

Thank you very much in advance.

```js
// app.module.js
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var myApp = angular
        .module("myApp", ["child"]);

    myApp.constant("config", {
        rootURL: "components/"
        , version: "myApp1.0.0"
    })
})();

// app.component.js
(function(){

    "use strict";

    // Define controller
    function mainController(){
        this.$onInit = function() {
            var mainVM = this;

            mainVM.parent = {
                "lastName": "Smith"
                , "firstName": "Jordan"
            };
        };

    }

    // Define component
    var mainComponent = {
        controller: mainController
        , controllerAs: "mainVM"
    };

    // Register controller and component
    angular.module("myApp")
        .controller("mainController", mainController)
        .component("mainComponent", mainComponent);

})();

//components/child.module.js
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var child = angular.module("child", []);
    
    child.constant("childConfig", config);

})();

//components/child.component.js
(function(){
    "use strict";

    // Define controller
    function childController(config) {
        this.$onInit = function() {
            var vm = this;
            
            vm.getTemplateUrl = function(){
              return config.rootURL + 'child.html';
            }
            vm.rootURL = config.rootURL;
            vm.version = config.version;
            vm.child = {
              "firstName": "Jack"
            }
        };
        // end of $onInit()
    }

    // Define component
    var child = {
        //templateUrl: vm.getTemplateUrl + "child.html"
        //templateUrl: "components/child.html"
        template: "<ng-include src='vm.getTemplateUrl()'/>"
        , controller: childController
        , controllerAs: "vm"
        , bindings: {
            parent: "<"
        }
    };


    // Register controller and component
    angular.module("child")
        .controller("childController", childController)
        .component("child", child);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.component.js"></script>
    <script src="components/child.module.js"></script>
    <script src="components/child.component.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainVM">
    Parent: {{mainVM.parent.firstName}} {{mainVM.parent.lastName}}<br>
    <child parent="mainVM.parent"></child>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the point of defining the same constant twice? Just inject the config constant wherever you need it.

Comment: No I'm not defining the same constant twice. The actual app I'm working on is much bigger and have many levels. I need to use the parent constant in each child constant's definition, so they can be used in their own controllers. And when I update the rootURL, all the child URLs will be changed. I've updated the Plunker to demonstrate that.

Comment: Don't define a constant for your child configs. Define a service, where you can inject the root constant, and return an object containing fields whose value depend on the injected constant.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might've misunderstood the [`constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) factory's capabilities. It's not supposed to be mutable neither variable, therefore it won't be able to use another external provider to compose it's value, it'll only serve a plain value that is pure.

On the other hand, if you don't mind, a factory can be use to achieve the result your are looking for. Basically you can create a factory that fabricate a string for you based on the injected `config` provider.

For example:

```
child.factory("childConfigURL", ['config', function(config) {
    return config.rootURL + "/component/";
}]);
```

The only problem with this approach is that it can't be injected into a module configuration function, because it's not pure anymore and needs to be bootstrapped to resolve it's dependencies.

> **Note on constants:**
>
> `constant(name, value);`
>
> Register a constant service with the $injector, such as a string, a
>   number, an array, an object or a function. Like the value, it is not
>   possible to inject other services into a constant.
>
> But unlike value, a constant can be injected into a module
>   configuration function (see angular.Module) and it cannot be
>   overridden by an AngularJS decorator.
>
> Ref.: [$provide.constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question.